# Text Services Keep Losing Their Keyboard Shortcuts in Mac OS Sierra

Tags: automator, services

I keep having the repeated problem of the **Mac text services losing the keyboard shortcuts** that I assign to them (in System Preferences > Keyboard Pane > Shortcuts > Services), ever since upgrading to Mac OS 10.12 Sierra.

I have a large set of **Automator workflow text services** that I use, and I assign **keyboard shortcuts** to each of these text services for speed of access. For example, I've set up a workflow that inputs the current text selection, and uses that to search eBay. My keyboard shortcut for this text service is Ctrl-Command E.

However, every now and then, all the keyboard shortcuts I assign in the System Preferences simply disappear (except for the default shortcuts, which remain).

This is very annoying, because it takes a while to re-enter all the shortcuts again, and I keep having to do this, as they keep disappearing. Often they will disappear after I have added a new keyboard shortcut to a service.

Is anyone else having this problem, and are there any workarounds for this issue? This glitch never occurred before, until I upgraded to Sierra.

Does anyone know where the file containing the assigned keyboard shortcuts is located? At least if I could take a copy of this file, it would be easier for me to restore the keyboard shortcuts after they are mysteriously deleted.

By the way, I don't have iCloud switched on (I understand that keyboard shortcuts sync over iCloud, when iCloud is on).

(*Just for Google searching, some synonyms: Mac Keyboard Shortcuts, Apple Keyboard Shortcuts, Finder Keyboard Shortcuts, Disappearing, Vanishing, Losing, Reverting to Default*).

Comment: Having same issue. For me, it happens like this: - I've already setup about a dozen service shortcuts. - Everything's working fine.
- I decide I need another one.
- I enter it.
- All my previous shortcuts get wiped out (the default Apple one's remain, however).

Comment: Yes, exactly the same thing that happens to me: I will set up (all in one session) a dozen or so text service shortcuts in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services. These are all fine. But then when I come back say a few weeks later and add an additional shortcut, that's when all my shortcuts get deleted. Very annoying.

Comment: One workaround for this problem is saving a copy of the preference file that stores text service shortcuts: this is located at ~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist  At least then when your text service shortcuts get deleted, you can copy this pbs.plist file back into the Preferences folder, and it will reinstate the text service shortcuts.